# Does AtomicBoolean not have a negate() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Does `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean` not have a method that can atomically negate/invert the value?  Can I do it another way?  Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't get what is wrong with boolean b = ab.get(); ab.compareAndSet(b, !b); You are guaranteed to flip what you got in the get. Is it really common to want to flip a boolean regardless of its current value at all times?

Comment: @Yishai: You are guaranteed to flip what you got in the get, but let's say you had `ab=true` and there were 2 togglers that had a race condition. The one that got there first toggled the bit, and the second said "oh, I've already been toggled" and therefore left it alone. This would leave `ab=false`, whereas if the toggle operations happened separately, it would leave `ab=true`. That's a bug. As for whether it's really common to toggle a boolean: It's very common in the case of hardware, not sure about pure software situations.

Comment: @Jason S, I think you are restating as a positive my question, at least in hardware (and therefore hardware simulation if nothing else) you would have a need for it. But I don't know that it is enough of a case for an API, though.

Comment: I've got a ping-pong buffer that could really use a getAndNegate() method in AtomicBoolean.

Answer (score 21):

Little old... but didn't really feel the answers were great.

Would have to totally disagree that this is not common or only useful in hardware. You may want a number of threads to toggle on a single variable with equal likelihood... I used the AtomicLong to make a fake boolean. This was adopted from a JMS MessageListener that I needed to respond a particular message half the time and another type the other half.

```
public class Mock {
    private static AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong(0);

    public boolean respond() {
        long currentCount = count.getAndIncrement();

        if (currentCount % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

My naive implementation would be this:

```
boolean v;
do {
  v=atomicBoolean.get();
} while(!atomicBoolean.compareAndSet(v, !v));
```

Comment: Beats having to synchronize :)

Comment: No, it doesn't because the toggle isn't atomic. The value of the AtomicBoolean can change between calling get() and calling compareAndSet()

Comment: @skaffman: in which case the compareAndSet() will fail, return false and the loop will be re-entered. Correct me if I got anything wrong.

Comment: This is essentially similar to how AtomicInteger incrementAndGet works.         for (;;) {
            int current = get();
            int next = current + 1;
            if (compareAndSet(current, next))
                return next;
        }

Comment: @pjp *Beats having to synchronize :)* In certain situations it most certainly does **not**. Confucius says one must learn balance.

Comment: Why would this not be implemented in AtomicBoolean?

Answer (score 6):

You can emulate `AtomicBoolean.negate()` by using `AtomicInteger.getAndIncrement()` and considering even numbers as `true` and odd numbers as `false`.
The actual value of the number should be ignored so you don't care about integer overflows.

Answer (score 3):

The solution suggested in the book [The CERT Oracle Secure Coding Standard for Java](https://books.google.de/books?id=FDun60sHwUgC&pg=PA314&lpg=PA314&dq=atomicboolean+toggle&source=bl&ots=_hZ-lOC6AW&sig=WnYDRP1GsUKsLJNxn6F3Ef5ty9Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIurG68ejXAhUO_aQKHbsSAvcQ6AEIVzAG#v=onepage&q=atomicboolean%20toggle&f=false) is the following:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

final class Flag {
    private AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    public void toggle() {
        boolean temp;
        do {
            temp = flag.get();
        } while(!flag.compareAndSet(temp, !temp));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [AtomicBoolean#compareAndSet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#compareAndSet-boolean-boolean-) method and a while loop you can implement a method to toggle the value of an AtomicBoolean in a thread-safe manner like this:

```java
public static boolean negate(AtomicBoolean ab) {
    // get the oposite value
    boolean newVal = !ab.get();

    // try to set the new value if the current value is the oposite of the new value
    while (!ab.compareAndSet(!newVal, newVal)) {
        // if the value we try to set was already set in the mean-time
        // then toggle the new value and try again
        newVal = !newVal;
    }
    // return the value we finally could set
    return newVal;
}
```

Comment: @jtahlborn I think you are wrong. I did a test with 50 concurrent threads trying to toggle the AtomicBoolean 10.000 times while waiting randomly between each iteration for 0-5ms. All threads completed. Would you care to explain the situation in which you think this method would not complete? The difference between my implementation and the currently highest rated is that
mine does not do the useless and expensive #get() call in each iteration of the while loop but instead toggles the local value and then tries to set it.

Comment: the other solution uses the current value so that it has a legitimate choice as to what to set it to.  you "guess" that the new value should be the opposite.  this may be right, it may be wrong.  "never complete" was probably not a very accurate statement.  however, your version "guesses" at the correct value (possibility of faster success or spurious failure), the other version uses current information to choose the next value (another get call but with higher expectation of success).  i guess it comes down to which mode of operation you prefer.

Comment: @jtahlborn In Nichola's versions the .get() and the .compareAndSet() call are not executed within a single atomic operation, thus the value of .get() may already be outdated the moment .compareAndSet() is called, so it has the same probability of being the right value as in my case where I am simply toggling the local value and try again, which safes one volatile read per iteration.

Comment: i'm not sure how you reason that they have the same probability of correctness.  it is possible for both pieces of code to be wrong, yes.

Comment: I think this solution is prone to a livelock if other thread are trying to set the same AtomicBoolean instance on the negate value you may be stuck in the while-loop in different threads

Comment: That is not the case, (in worst case) on every second iteration one of the threads will succeed until eventually all threads could flip the boolean. There is also no issue with visibility and memory barriers since newVal is a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with java 9 or later I suggest:

```
    /**
     * Flip the AtomicBoolean.
     * Sets the boolean value to false if it is true, and to true if it is false
     * with memory effects as specified by {@link java.lang.invoke.VarHandle#setVolatile}.
     *
     * @param atomicBoolean atomicBoolean
     * @return new boolean value of AtomicBoolean
     * @see AtomicInteger#accumulateAndGet(int x, IntBinaryOperator accumulatorFunction)
     * @since 9
     */
    public static final boolean flip(AtomicBoolean atomicBoolean) {
        boolean prev = atomicBoolean.get(), next = false;
        for (boolean haveNext = false; ; ) {
            if (!haveNext) {
                next = !prev;
            }
            if (atomicBoolean.weakCompareAndSetVolatile(prev, next)) {
                return next;
            }
            haveNext = (prev == (prev = atomicBoolean.get()));
        }
    }
```

Or if you want get it directly...

https://github.com/XenoAmess/commonx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xenoamess/commonx/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBooleanUtilsx.java