# Are nested method calls of AtomicInteger also atomic in java

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, java-5

Would this operation be atomic or is there a chance of data race in between?

```
atomicInteger.set(-atomicInteger.get());
```

If there is a data race, how to negate an `AtomicInteger` atomically?

Comment: No; that won't work.  See http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you need to synchronize to lock the instance I guess.

AtomicInteger has lots of methods to getAndSet but nothing to do inverse...

Apparently this was asked before on SO [Does AtomicBoolean not have a negate() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255617/does-atomicboolean-not-have-a-negate-method) The solution on that page is interesting.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way

```
public int getAndNegate(AtomicInteger i) {
    for (;;) {
        int current = i.get();
        int next = -current;
        if (i.compareAndSet(current, next))
            return current;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public final int getAndDecrement()
```

Atomically decrements by one the current value. Returns the previous value

```
AtomicInteger itsCounter = new AtomicInteger();
itsCounter.getAndDecrement();
```

Comment: Thanks but I was actually asking about negating and not decrementing the value